# Python created ETH address doesn't match Metamask

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain, metamask

I am working on a project working with the Ethereum blockchain.

Part of the project requires access to my own ETH wallet address.  However, when I run a check on my code, I don't generate my own address that I use for Metamask.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
from eth_account import Account

acct = Account.create('<my 12 seed words>')

acct.address
```

The address in acct.address is not mine.  I have copied my seed words exactly, copied from clipboard, and neither returns my wallet address.

Tried to create my ETH wallet address in Python using eth_account library and was unsuccessful

Answer (score 1):

Use `Account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic)` instead which should have the same format as Metamask (BIP39).

The function `Account.create()` does not take mnemonic as an argument, just anything random.